# Python Opencv Structured Forests Edge Detection TypeError

Tags: python, opencv, edge-detection

When I call the OpenCV Structured Forests Edge Detection in Python as shown below, I get an error:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('2009_005193.jpg')
gray_img = np.asarray(img.mean(axis=2) / 255, np.float32)
out = cv2.ximgproc_StructuredEdgeDetection.detectEdges(gray_img)
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gop1.py", line 19, in <module>
    out = cv2.ximgproc_StructuredEdgeDetection.detectEdges(gray_img)
TypeError: descriptor 'detectEdges' requires a 'cv2.ximgproc_StructuredEdgeDetection' object but received a 'numpy.ndarray'
```

In the documentation ([link to documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d8/d54/classcv_1_1ximgproc_1_1StructuredEdgeDetection.html)), it is present under ximgproc_StructuredEdgeDetection, as a function detectEdges().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the documentation, it will require 3-channel float 32 image. Perhaps you need to create the StructuredEdgeDetection Object first.
However, this worked for me:

```
imgrgb=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)/255
imgrgb=imgrgb.astype(np.float32)
model='structured edge/model.yml'
retval=cv2.ximgproc.createStructuredEdgeDetection(model)
out=retval.detectEdges(imgrgb)
```